# Why is the time delay of directly requesting the api and js requesting the api very different?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, performance, go

### Question

I wonder Why the time delay is different between directly requesting the api and js requesting the api.
The former is about half the time of the latter.

### screenshot

1. request in js, as a xhr-type
   [image]
2. request directly by browser, as a document-type
   [image]
3. then time estimated above is about TTFB(Time To First Byte)
   [image]

Comment: Could possibly be a couple of things. Are there a bunch of other requests the browser is making at the same time? Also when it is being requested via JS it will most likely have CORS. This means it normally sends an OPTIONS request first to validate the CORS settings from the server.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes, you're right. I found the reason is that when i click a button, it issues lots of requests at once, and the server is poor of handling multiple requests.